# Delete data with angular 6 and laravel 5.6

Tags: angular, laravel, angular6, laravel-5.6

I am implementing delete functionality with angular6 and laravel. But at some point i got stuck

List.component.html

```
    <button class="delete-wrap" (click)="deletelist(contact.id)">
```

List.component.ts

```
deletelist(id){
  console.log(id);
  this.Jarwis.deleteList(id).subscribe(res=>{
  console.log(res);

});
```

In jarwis service

```
deleteList(id){
   alert(id);
   return this.http.post(`${this.baseUrl}/deleteList`,id)
}
```

And my api.php of laravel is as below

```
  Route::post('deleteList', 'AddListController@deleteList');
```

In AddListController

```
  public function deleteList($id)
  {
    echo $id;
  }
```

When i try to echo the id in deleteList method of AddListController is says

```
    Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\AddListController::deleteList(), 0 passed and exactly 1 expected
```

Iam getting the id till deleteList of Jarwis service. What am I missing?

Comment: I would recommend using `http.delete` for a delete api call (from angular side).

Comment: Route::post('deleteList', 'AddListController@deleteList'); for this api call you have to send data in param as said by @Jonas Borsch. or if you want to delete without using param then follow tayyab_fareed answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to accept `id` in the route

```
  Route::post('deleteList/{id}', 'AddListController@deleteList');
```